# The properties expression is not valid. The expression should represent a property

Tags: entity-framework-6

I have these two entities

```
public class Song : IPathHavingEntity
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string Path { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public virtual Album Album { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public int TrackNumber { get; set; }
    }

public class Album : IPathHavingEntity
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string Path { get; set; }
        public virtual IEnumerable<Song> Songs { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public int AlbumNumber { get; set; }
    }
```

`Path` is defined in the `IPathHavingEntity` interface.

In my Seed method I want to add a song to the `Songs` table only if it doesn't exist.  For this reason I check that the album path and song path combination don't exist already before adding it thus

```
context.Songs.AddOrUpdate(
    s => new { FilePath = s.Path, AlbumPath = s.Album.Path }, 
    new Song { TrackNumber = 1, Path = "01 Intro.mp3", Album = one });
```

The problem is I get this error

``` The properties expression 's => new <>f__AnonymousType0``2(FilePath = 
s.Path, AlbumPath = s.Album.Path)' is not valid. The expression should 
represent a   property: C#: 't => t.MyProperty'  VB.Net: 'Function(t) t.MyProperty'. When specifying multiple properties use an anonymous type: C#: 't => new { t.MyProperty1, t.MyProperty2 }'  VB.Net: 'Function(t) New With { t.MyProperty1, t.MyProperty2 }'. ```

What's the problem?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I struggled with a similar issue for several hours today and was finally able to resolve it.  I'm not sure if this will work for your situation but it's worth investigating.

The problem may be caused by the `Album` property of your `Song` entity being marked as `virtual`.  I'm not an EF expert but I don't think it likes that `virtual` property when initializing your anonymous type.  Add a non-virtual property for the album path (but keep the `virtual` navigation property), like this:

```
public class Song : IPathHavingEntity
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Path { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public virtual Album Album { get; set; }

    public string AlbumPath { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int TrackNumber { get; set; }
}
```

And then perform the `AddOrUpdate` using that non-virtual property, like this:

```
context.Songs.AddOrUpdate(
    s => new { FilePath = s.Path, AlbumPath = s.AlbumPath }, 
    new Song { TrackNumber = 1, Path = "01 Intro.mp3", Album = one });
```

EF should then only allow you to add songs where the given song path and album path do not already exist.  Whether your `Song` domain object can have a non-virtual `AlbumPath` property is another question but this should at least allow you to run your seed method in the way you described.

Answer (score 60):

In my case, The Only modification I did that on the Model Classes forget to put `{get; set;}` with the property declaration, Thus ...It's solved my problem.

Like this:

Before:

```
 public int Supplier_ID;
 public String Supplier_Code;
```

After:

```
 public int Supplier_ID { get; set; }
 public String Supplier_Code { get; set; }
```

Kindly Check your Model Classes should have the `Get/Set` property

Comment: I literally facepalmed when I saw this answer, and I was looking for a good half hour with a simple primary key.  Thank you!

Comment: After seeing so many answers on the internet with people using Where clauses and Select clauses on their Includes and ThenIncludes, this is the answer that fixed my issue.

Comment: This was my mistake too. Dang what a silly way to lose time of development. Thank you!

Answer (score 6):

EF does not create a column for a property which does not have either getters or setters. For example, EF will not create columns for the following City and Age properties.

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

public class Student
{
    private int _age = 0;

    public int StudentId { get; set; }
    public string StudentName { get; set; }
    public string City { get{ return StudentName;}  }
    public int Age { set{ _age = value;}  }
}
```

Referance : https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/notmapped-dataannotations-attribute-in-code-first.aspx

Answer (score 0):

In my case, changing the following values in the mapper worked.

From:

```
this.HasKey(t => new { FirstName = t.FirstName, LastName = t.LastName });
```

To:

```
this.HasKey(t => new { t.FirstName, t.LastName });
```

Answer (score 0):

What has not been mentioned in any of other answers is that the source of the problem in any case shown is the same: The "custom identification expression" passed in as a parameter of the [AddOrUpdate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.entity.migrations.dbsetmigrationsextensions.addorupdate?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev16.query%3FappId%3DDev16IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbSetMigrationsExtensions.AddOrUpdate%60%601);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version%3Dv4.7.2);k(DevLang-csharp)%26rd%3Dtrue&view=entity-framework-6.2.0) method has to be a valid property of the entity being inserted or updated. Also, it will not accept ComplextType.Property there.

For example:

```
context.Songs.AddOrUpdate(
    s => new { k.Path, k.AlbumPath }, 
    new Song { TrackNumber = 1, Path = "01 Intro.mp3", Album = one });
```

Note that the problem was resolved when the AlbumPath was used and also note that the anonymous type requires no other fields to be created. Instead, you just need to specify the property names.

It worth mentioning to be careful when using AddOrUpdate as [the result can be destructive](https://www.michaelgmccarthy.com/2016/08/24/entity-framework-addorupdate-is-a-destructive-operation/).