# How to use a virtual property when initializing anonymous type Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, anonymous-types

When trying to seed my database I am using the anonymous type like this:

```
context.CalibrationTargets.AddOrUpdate(x => new { calId = x.CalibrationSetup.Id, targetIndex = x.TargetIndex },
            new CalibrationTarget()...
```

However because `CalibrationSetup` is a virtual property I seem to get the error:

> The properties expression `x => new <>f__AnonymousType102(calId = x.CalibrationSetup.Id, targetIndex = x.TargetIndex)` is not valid. The expression should represent a property: C#: `t => t.MyProperty`  VB.Net: `Function(t) t.MyProperty`. When specifying multiple properties use an anonymous type: C#: `t => new { t.MyProperty1, t.MyProperty2 }` VB.Net: `Function(t) New With { t.MyProperty1, t.MyProperty2 }

Also after reading this post [The properties expression is not valid. The expression should represent a property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20169376/the-properties-expression-is-not-valid-the-expression-should-represent-a-proper/34279425), the problem seem to be because of the fact that `CalibrationSetup` is a `virtual` property.

Is there a way I can get around this without having to populate the database with another `Calibration_Id` column that isn't `virtual` to use in the anonymous type?

Comment: have you tried `x => new { x.CalibrationSetup.Id, x.TargetIndex }` ?

Comment: @tschmit007 yeah, get the same error using that

Comment: So CalibrationSetup is a child of CalibrationTarget? Expose the FK in the parent and use that (CalibrationTarget.CalibrationSetup_Id).

Comment: @SteveGreene CalibrationTarget is a child of CalibrationSetup

Answer (score 0):

Hard to work without seeing the models, but to seed CalibrationTargets you will probably want something like below. Your syntax for `AddOrUpdate` also looks off. You have to have known values you are going to seed with.

```
context.CalibrationTargets.AddOrUpdate(
    x => x.CalibrationTargetId,  // This is the field that determines uniqueness 
    new CalibrationTarget
    {
        CalibrationTargetId = 1,  // if this is an identity column, omit and use a different field above for uniqueness
        TargetIndex = 99,  // what value for target index? Fixed value or variable can be used
        CalibrationSetup = new CalibrationSetup { Id = 77 }  // Same as above comment
    },
    new CalibrationTarget
    {
        CalibrationTargetId = 2,  // if this is an identity column, omit and use a different field above for uniqueness
        TargetIndex = 88,  // what value for target index? Fixed value or variable can be used
        CalibrationSetup = new CalibrationSetup { Id = 66 }  // Same as above comment
    }
    ... repeat for all seeded records
    );

context.SaveChanges();
```

If the FK CalibrationSetupId is exposed, you could simplify.