# How to use HasPrincipalKey with a "Composite Key" that is not defined in schema

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I am using Oracle Entity Framework Core v6.21.5 and ASP.NET Core.

I have one table, I'll call `TableA`, which has a primary key I'll call `TableA.Id`.

I have another table, I'll call `TableB` which references `TableA` but via a combination of fields that are not declared as any sort of key on `TableA`. I'll just call this `TableB.FK_Composite1`+`TableB.FK_Composite2`. These two fields uniquely identify a row in `TableA`, but they are not identified in the database schema.

Using the concept of a [principal key](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships?tabs=fluent-api%2Cfluent-api-composite-key%2Ccomposite-key#principal-key), I have configured the navigation property in `TableB` as follows:

```
// Declared amongst other entity properties
public TableA TableA { get; set; }
...
// Within the Entity configuration
TableB.HasOne(fk => fk.TableA)
      .WithMany()
      .HasForeignKey(fk => new { fk.FK_Composite1, fk.FK_Composite2 })
      .HasPrincipalKey(fk => new { fk.Column1, fk.Column2});
```

However, when I run my code and the model configuration is called, I end up with this error:

> The expression 'fk => new <>f__AnonymousType0`2(Column1 = fk.FK_Composite1, Column2 = fk.FK_Composite2 )' is not a valid member access expression. The expression should represent a simple property or field access: 't => t.MyProperty'. When specifying multiple properties or fields, use an anonymous type: 't => new { t.MyProperty, t.MyField }'. (Parameter 'memberAccessExpression')

Any clues as to where I am going wrong here? I've tried to include just the information necessary for my question but I am happy to provide more context. This is my first time posting a question so go easy on me :)

I have reviewed similar questions such as
[The properties expression is not valid. The expression should represent a property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20169376/the-properties-expression-is-not-valid-the-expression-should-represent-a-proper)
[The properties expression is not valid. The expression should represent a property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20169376/the-properties-expression-is-not-valid-the-expression-should-represent-a-proper)

I have verified that I have getters/setters and have tried both with and without `virtual` on the navigation property.

Edit #1 - extra info requested by Rena:

```
public class TableA 
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public long Column1 { get; set; }
    public string Column2 { get; set; }

    public static void ConfigureModelBuilder(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<TableA>(e =>
        {
            e.ToTable("TABLE_A");
            e.HasKey(k => k.Id);

            e.Property(c => c.Id)
             .HasColumnName("ID")
             .HasColumnType("NUMBER(12)");

            e.Property(c => c.Column1 )
             .HasColumnName("COLUMN_1")
             .HasColumnType("NUMBER(12)");

            e.Property(c => c.Column2 )
             .HasColumnName("COLUMN_2")
             .HasColumnType("VARCHAR2(10)");
        }
    }
}
```

```
public class TableB 
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public long FK_Composite1 { get; set; }
    public string FK_Composite2 { get; set; }

    public TableA TableA { get; set;}

    public static void ConfigureModelBuilder(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<TableB>(e =>
        {
            e.ToTable("TABLE_B");
            e.HasKey(k => k.Id);

            e.Property(c => c.FK_Composite1)
             .HasColumnName("FK_COMPOSITE_1")
             .HasColumnType("NUMBER(12)");

            e.Property(c => c.FK_Composite2)
             .HasColumnName("FK_COMPOSITE_2")
             .HasColumnType("VARCHAR2(10)");

            e.HasOne(fk => fk.TableA)
             .WithMany()
             .HasForeignKey(fk => new { fk.FK_Composite1, fk.FK_Composite2 })
             .HasPrincipalKey(fk => new { fk.Column1, fk.Column2});
        }
    }
}
```

The DB context has two public DbSet properties for `TableA` and `TableB` and calls `ConfigureModelBuilder` on both of them in `OnModelCreating`. The error occurs when `TableB.ConfigureModelBuilder(modelBuilder)` is called. I believe it is specifically erroring on the lines where the relationship to `TableA` is configured for `TableB`. `e.HasOne(fk => fk.TableA)`...

Comment: Hi @planedonut, pls share your two model design and your DbContext. Which line you runs makes such error?

Comment: Hey @Rena - I have added the info you requested. Let me know if that helps!

Comment: Hi @planedonut, it works fine in my project. Have you tried clear the migration file and remigrate again?